# Как выровнять текст по вертикали в grid с помощью css?

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid, alignment

Сверстала макет на *grid*. Хочу выровнять текст по вертикали. Свойство *align-items* работает не так, как надо - оно выравнивает текст, но и обрезает *background*, который я задала:

[image]

А надо, чтобы ячейка оставалась полностью закрашена:

[image]

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: black;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.menu {
  grid-area: menu;
  background: #E33E54;
}

.hero {
  grid-area: hero;
  background: #4C858B;
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
  background: #B1B1B1;
}

.image {
  grid-area: image;
  background: palegreen;
}

.extra {
  grid-area: extra;
  background: cadetblue;
}

.banner {
  grid-area: banner;
  background: yellow;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: system-ui;
  grid-template-columns: 25% repeat(3, 25%);
  grid-template-rows: 7vh 53vh repeat(3, 13.33vh);
  text-align: center;
  grid-template-areas: "header menu menu menu" "hero hero hero hero" "main main . image" "main main . extra" "banner banner banner banner";
  @media all and (max-width: 768px) {
    grid-template-columns: 25% 50% 25%;
    grid-template-rows: 7vh 53vh repeat(3, 13.33vh);
    grid-template-areas: "header header header" "hero hero hero" "menu main main" "menu banner banner" "menu extra image ";
  }
  @media all and (max-width: 414px) {
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: 6vh 6vh 25vh 25vh repeat(3, 13vh);
    grid-template-areas: "header" "menu" "hero" "main" "banner" "extra" "image";
  }
}

.grid-item {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Adaptive</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="scss/style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid-container">

    <header class="header grid-item">
      <p>header</p>
    </header>
    <menu class="menu grid-item">
      menu
    </menu>

    <div class="hero grid-item">
      hero
    </div>

    <main class="main grid-item">
      main
    </main>

    <!--<img class="image" src="img/shrek.jpg" alt="shrek =)">-->
    <div class=" image grid-item">
      image
    </div>
    <div class="extra grid-item">
      extra
    </div>


    <div class="banner grid-item ">
      banner
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать такой `.grid-item`

```
.grid-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: black;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.menu {
  grid-area: menu;
  background: #E33E54;
}

.hero {
  grid-area: hero;
  background: #4C858B;
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
  background: #B1B1B1;
}

.image {
  grid-area: image;
  background: palegreen;
}

.extra {
  grid-area: extra;
  background: cadetblue;
}

.banner {
  grid-area: banner;
  background: yellow;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: system-ui;
  grid-template-columns: 25% repeat(3, 25%);
  grid-template-rows: 7vh 53vh repeat(3, 13.33vh);
  text-align: center;
  grid-template-areas: "header menu menu menu" "hero hero hero hero" "main main . image" "main main . extra" "banner banner banner banner";
  @media all and (max-width: 768px) {
    grid-template-columns: 25% 50% 25%;
    grid-template-rows: 7vh 53vh repeat(3, 13.33vh);
    grid-template-areas: "header header header" "hero hero hero" "menu main main" "menu banner banner" "menu extra image ";
  }
  @media all and (max-width: 414px) {
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: 6vh 6vh 25vh 25vh repeat(3, 13vh);
    grid-template-areas: "header" "menu" "hero" "main" "banner" "extra" "image";
  }
}

.grid-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Adaptive</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="scss/style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid-container">

    <header class="header grid-item">
      <p>header</p>
    </header>
    <menu class="menu grid-item">
      menu
    </menu>

    <div class="hero grid-item">
      hero
    </div>

    <main class="main grid-item">
      main
    </main>

    <!--<img class="image" src="img/shrek.jpg" alt="shrek =)">-->
    <div class=" image grid-item">
      image
    </div>
    <div class="extra grid-item">
      extra
    </div>


    <div class="banner grid-item ">
      banner
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень выручили